# Message passing using Actors

Tags: scala

I am writing a program using Actors in scala in which an actor (Actor1) accepts two numbers as command line arguments and sends a message to another actor Actor2 (which calculates their sum). Actor2 sends the result to Actor1, who prints it on the screen.

```
class Actor1 extends Actor {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {   
    val n= Integer.parseInt(args(0))  
    val k= Integer.parseInt(args(1))  
    val actor2 = new Actor2   
    actor2 ! (n, k)  
  }

def act()
{    
           react{
                    case num: Integer =>
                    println(num)
                    case _=>
                    println("Sum not received")
                    exit

                   } 
}   
}
 class Actor2 extends Actor  {
    def act(){
       loop
       {
       react
            {
            case(n:Int, k:Int) =>
            val i = n + k
            val actor1 = new Actor1
             actor1 ! i}
         }
     }
    }
```

Is it possible to define main() inside the class that extends Actor, and is there any other way to accept command line arguments by the Actor?
It shows the error: class Actor1 needs to be abstract, since method act in trait Reactor of type ()Unit is not defined.

Comment: Main needs to be in an object, not a class.

Comment: @TonyK.I tried object in place of class for Actor1, but it gives a similar error: object creation impossible, since method act in trait Reactor of type ()Unit is not defined

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You should consider using [akka](http://akka.io) instead of the default Scala actors. It's just better.. in pretty much every aspect.

That aside, here are a few answers for your:

- Your main method should be in a standalone object (not a companion object). So use something like this: `object Main { def main(args:Array[String]) { ... } }` and start your program via the `Main` object/class. (This is due to the definition inside the `Actor1` class being non-static and the problem that if you define a companion object the .class filenames collide.)
- In your code, something seems to have gone wrong with the brackets - or did you place `Actor2` inside the `Actor1` class on purpose? It's cleaner, if you just make three separate classes/objects: `Actor1, Actor2, Main`.
- When you create Scala actors, you have to explicitly start them (not so with akka 2.x). So you miss your calls to `actor1.start` and such. Note that your program will then not terminate before your actors have terminated, so don't wonder if it doesn't stop anymore after you add that.
- Finally, some minor hints:

  - You may want to consider using `!?` and send back your answer to the original caller, as this also allows you to have a proper termination condition.
  - `Integer.parseInt("0")` can be written more simply as  `"0".toInt`